# How to clone from local (file:///) SVN repository with hgsvn?

Tags: svn, hgsubversion

At the moment I am trying to get a clone of a remote subversion repository running. The remote repository is only available over a very slow link, so I went with `svnsync` to create a local subversion repository. After nearly thirty hours I now have the local copy of the subversion repository.

How can I now clone this to a new mercurial repository? Problem being that neither of the following forms using `file:///` appear to work:

```
$ hg clone svn+file:///home/user/repo repo.hg
abort: repository svn+file:///home/user/repo not found!
$ hg clone file+svn:///home/user/repo repo.hg
abort: repository file+svn:///home/user/repo not found!
$ hg clone file:///home/user/repo repo.hg
abort: repository /home/user/repo not found!
```

Conversely `svn info file:///home/user/repo` *does* give me the info and proves there is a proper subversion repository in that place. `svn://` obviously makes no sense as I am not running the server locally.

I also tried:

```
$ hgimportsvn file:///home/user/repo repo.hg
SVN branch isn't a copy
Finished! You can now pull all SVN history with 'hgpullsvn'.
```

but the `hgpullsvn` only succeeds for the first half dozen revisions and then errors out:

```
Interrupted, please wait for cleanup!

External program failed (return code 1): hg '--encoding' 'utf-8' 'remove' '-A' 'branches/Company/CVSROOT'
branches/Company/CVSROOT: No such file or directory
```

(The `CVSROOT` stems from a previous conversion *to* Subversion from CVS, apparently. This was before my time.)

Does `hgsvn` not understand the `file:///` protocol specifier even if I try to force it with `svn+file:///`?

NB: I have tried to clone via `hg` and `hgsvn` before, but then ended up getting errors when synchronizing via `hgsvn` after a while. Since cloning the whole history takes so long I went with the local subversion repository copy from which I intended to clone via `hgsvn` as I did in the past the remote one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just opinion: don't use hgsvn, which "is in maintenance mode" from 2010, add hgsubversion extension to Mercurial and clone Subversion repository with it

**PS:** "svn+" prefix will be useful only for http-served repositories (because you can use http:// for Subversion, Mercurial, Git). Local Subversion repo (in clone with hgsubversion) will be file:///

Comment: Wait, there is a difference between `hgsvn` and `hgsubversion`. Wow. This fact completely eluded me until now. +1 for the answer for now. I'll have to test it with the alternative extension first. Yes, I'm aware `svn+` is used to remove ambiguity, which might make sense on local repos, too, though.

Comment: works, thanks. I just didn't realize these were two different projects.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem again. This is one symptom of a misconfigured or not installed `hgsubversion` extension as well.

Make sure you have the appropriate lines in your `.hgrc` or `Mercurial.ini` (global or local) as pointed out [on the documentation site for HgSubversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion). Example (adjust the path as needed):

```
[extensions]
hgsubversion = ~/hgsubversion/hgsubversion
```

Then check with:

```
hg help hgsubversion
hg help subversion
```

My guess would be that without the extension Hg simply has no idea what to expect in the folder and so expects a Mercurial repo, which it cannot find.

In my case this was caused *again* by overwriting a local `~/.hgrc`.